# Automatically created indexes in postgresql: combined index on key attributes?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm not sure which indexes postgresql AUTOMATICALLY creates; I think it will create one on Book(ibsn), because its the primary key, and also Book(title), because its a candidate key... but I'm not sure if postgres will automatically create a combined index on all key attributes Book(ibsn, title). Also, would it create any other indexes automatically?

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
 isbn       INTEGER CONSTRAINT B_ISBN CHECK (ISBN BETWEEN 1 AND 2000),
 title      VARCHAR(200) CONSTRAINT B_TITLE NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 author     VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT B_AUTH NOT NULL,
 cost       FLOAT DEFAULT 0.00,
 lent_date  DATE,
 returnDate DATE,
 times_lent INTEGER,
 sectionID  SMALLINT,
 CONSTRAINT BOOK_PRIME PRIMARY KEY (isbn),
 CONSTRAINT BOOK_SECT FOREIGN KEY (sectionID) REFERENCES Section(sectionID) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres will automatically create indexes only for:

- [primary keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS): *Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key*
- [unique constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS): *Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint*

In your case, Postgres creates one unique index on the column `isbn` and one unique index on the column `unique` because you declared each column individually to be unique, not the combination of both.

No other indexes will be created automatically.